# psutil vs dd: monitoring disk I/O

Tags: python-3.x, dd, psutil

I'm writing y.a.t. (yet-another-tool :)) for monitoring disk usage on Linux.
I'm using *python 3.3.2* and *psutil 3.3.0*.

The process I'm monitoring does something really basic: I use the *dd* tool and I vary the **block size** (128, 512, 1024, 4096)

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if=./bigfile.txt of=./copy.img bs=4096
```

bigfile.txt:

```
$ stat bigfile.txt 
     File: ‘bigfile.txt’
     Size: 87851423     Blocks: 171600     IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

And the snippet of the monitor is as follows:

```
def poll(interval, proc):
    d_before = proc.io_counters()
    time.sleep(interval)
    tst = time.time()
    d_after = proc.io_counters()

    usage = OrderedDict.fromkeys(d_after.__dict__.keys())
    for k, v in usage.items():
        usage[k] = d_after.__dict__[k] - d_before.__dict__[k]

    return tst, usage
```

At each run, I clear the cache (as suggested many times on stackoverflow):

```
rm copy.img && sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

**My question is: why aren't the numbers matching?**

**bs=128**:

dd:

```
686339+1 records in
686339+1 records out
87851423 bytes (88 MB) copied, 1.21664 s, 72.2 MB/s
```

monitor.py:

```
1450778750.104943 OrderedDict([('read_count', 686352), ('write_count', 686343), ('read_bytes', 87920640), ('write_bytes', 87855104)])
```

**bs=4096**

dd:

```
21448+1 records in
21448+1 records out
87851423 bytes (88 MB) copied, 0.223911 s, 392 MB/s
```

monitor.py:

```
1450779294.5541275 OrderedDict([('read_count', 21468), ('write_count', 21452), ('read_bytes', 88252416), ('write_bytes', 87855104)])
```

The difference is still there with all the values of *bs*.

Is it a matter of certains read/write not being counted? Does psutil performs some extra work? For example, with *bs=4096*, why in psutil 400993 more bytes (for read) and 3681 (for write) are reported?

Am I missing something big?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**: as an update, it doesn't matter the granularity of timings in the measurement, i.e., the time.sleep(interval) call. I tried with different values, and summing up the total number of reads and writes reported by psutil. The difference remains.

**EDIT2**: typo in snippet code

Comment: Sorry for being lazy, but can you tell me exactly which number is the wrong one?

Comment: Andrea, I don't have any idea. My point is: why aren't they the same? If the process dd reads X bytes, I expect that psutil reports me that X bytes were read by the process: this is not happening.

Comment: What I mean is: in this line `1450778750.104943 OrderedDict([...])` there are five numbers. Which of these five numbers should I look at? (And, by the way, which numbers from `dd` should I look at?)

Comment: read_bytes from psutil, bytes copied from dd.

Answer (score 3):

### `write_bytes`

The `read_bytes` and `write_bytes` correspond to the same fields from `/proc/<PID>/io`. Quoting the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=HEAD#n1502) (emphasis mine):

```
read_bytes
----------

I/O counter: bytes read
Attempt to count the number of bytes which this process really did cause to
be fetched from the storage layer. Done at the submit_bio() level, so it is
accurate for block-backed filesystems. 


write_bytes
-----------

I/O counter: bytes written
Attempt to count the number of bytes which this process caused to be sent to
the storage layer. This is done at page-dirtying time.
```

As you know, most (all?) filesystems are block-based. This implies that if you have a program that, say, writes just 5 bytes to a file, and if your block size if 4 KiB, then 4 KiB will be written.

If you don't trust `dd`, let's try with a simple Python script:

```
with open('something', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'12345')
input('press Enter to exit')
```

This script should write only 5 bytes, but if we inspect `/proc/<PID>/io`, we can see that 4 KiB were written:

```
$ cat /proc/3455/io 
rchar: 215317
wchar: 24
syscr: 66
syscw: 2
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 4096
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

This is the same thing that is happening with `dd` in your case.

You have asked `dd` to write 87851423 bytes. How many 4 KiB blocks are 87851423 bytes?

```
87851423 - (87851423 mod 4096) + 4096 = 87855104
```

Not by chance 87855104 is the number reported by psutil.

### `read_bytes`

How about `read_bytes`? In theory we should have `read_bytes` equal to `write_bytes`, but actually `read_bytes` shows 16 more blocks in the first run, and 97 more blocks in the second run.

Well, first of all, let's see what files `dd` is actually reading:

```
$ strace -e trace=open,read -- dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=1M count=2
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\v\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY)             = 3
open("zero", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
read(0, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1048576) = 1048576
read(0, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1048576) = 1048576
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 0
read(0, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As you can see, `dd` is opening and reading the linker, the GNU C library, and locale files. It is reading more bytes than you can see above, because it's also using `mmap`, not just `read`.

The point is: `dd` reads many more files than the source file, therefore it's acceptable the `read_bytes` is much higher than `write_bytes`. But why is it inconsistent?

Those files that are read by `dd` are also used by many other programs. Even if you `drop_caches` just before executing `dd`, there are chances that some other process may reload one of these files into memory. You can try with this very simple C program:

```
int main()
{
    while(1) {
    }
}
```

Compiled with the default GCC options, this program does nothing except opening the linker and the GNU C library. If you try to `drop_caches`, execute the program and `cat /proc/<PID>/IO` more than once, you'll see that `read_bytes` will vary across runs (except if you perform the steps very fast, in which case the probability that some other program has loaded some files into the cache is low).